# 2006 ford 500 hesitation/lose of power when accelerating and more so when ac/heat is on

Tags: engine, ford, idle, hesitation

I have a 2006 ford 500 and having lose of power when accelerating, gets worst if I turn on ac/heat. Just started doing it a 2 months ago and it’s not getting any better with new mass air flow, fuel pump, and filter. The check engine light isn’t on. I’m at lost, put new spark plugs, coil packs, and fuel injectors on as well, and still having the same problems. Help!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: What is the mileage on the odometer ?